# Changes label position in Google Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using regular 3D pie chart from Google visualization like this one

`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});

  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],

      ['Work',     11],

      ['Eat',      2],

      ['Commute',  2],

      ['Watch TV', 2],

      ['Sleep',    7]

    ]);

    var options = {

      title: 'My Daily Activities',

      is3D: true,

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));

    chart.draw(data, options);

  }

</script>
```

```
<div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

`

I would like to ask a question, how I want put label under pie chart ?

I can't find anything how to customize the label position.

Comment: there is not a config option to place the title below. instead remove the title from the chart, and place an html element with the title under the chart